# Hydrocarbons and their derivatives

Tags: hydrocarbons

Which alcohol is used in spirit lamp?

Accoding to my text book, the answer given for this question is Ethyl Alcohol but one of my teachers told me that it is Methyl Alcohol.

Please somebody help me with this question.

Answer (score 1):

the methylated spirit is used in spirit lamp.

but methylated spirit contains methyl alcohol & ethyl alcohol both.

I think, it should be Ethyl alcohol.